# 'colorButtonNormal' working as on press state

Tags: android, xml, button

I am customizing button style

```
<style name="custom_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#f37022</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Using as

```
<Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Prepaid Package"
       style="@style/custom_button"/>`
```

But the color on `colorButtonNormal` has appears on `On press` state.

What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken the example from here.

[Custom background](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

If you want to customise the background depending on the state of the button:

create an xml file eg button_custom.xml in res/drawable/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

then for the actual button, add: You can incorporate your default with your custom background.

```
<Button
   ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"  />
```

Also in your styles, to fix the background color of your custom button style:

```
<item name="android:background">#f37022</item>
```

`"colorButtonNormal"` is not an attribute of button, you need to use the built in attributes, as you have for the other items.

Comment: `colorButtonNormal` supposed to be work on `normal state` but it is working as `on pressed` state.

I know the way as answered. But I want to define the style on styles.xml